# FB Comments Implementation in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, facebook, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to implement fb comments in Windows phone. I tried using Web view as below

```
<WebView x:Name="FBCommentsTest"></WebView>
```

Code behind C#

```
FBCommentsTest.NavigateToString("<html><head></head><body><div id=\"fb-root\"></div><div id=\"fb-root\"></div><script>(function(d, s, id) {var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if (d.getElementById(id)) return;js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;js.src = \"http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=" + APP_KEY + "\";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script><div class=\"fb-comments\" data-href=\""
                + mExternalUrl + "\" data-width=\"500\"></div> </body></html>");
```

But it didn't get the desired output. Web View  displays as an empty page. Please someone guide to achieve this